# Is php version 7.0.23 okay for Magento 2.1.7?

Tags: error, installation, magento-2.1.7, php-7, custom-theme

My PHP version 7.0.23, and my Magento version 2.1.7, actually i need to install theme only. after run setup wizard i am getting an error like,

[image]

May i know what is the error and how can i solve it?

Comment: is you server is support mutiple server?

Comment: How can i check it? Actually, i am trying to install localhost...

Comment: check in command php-v which version showing

Comment: My php ver 7.0.24.

Comment: Please see below i will explain my details...

Comment: @SunilPatel did you get my point, is am do any changes?

Comment: do you want to just add theme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69207/discussion-between-zus-and-sunil-patel).

Answer (score 0):

Refer This link, Supported version for magento 2 php 7.0.2 ,7.0.4 and 7.0.6–7.0.x
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: I have installed my Magento 2, no error. If i try to install Magento2 them like move app and pub folder root path, then go running, Magento 2 setup wizard, there only i am getting the error?  How can i solve the error?

Comment: can you explain clearly zus. what the exact problem.

Comment: Let me explain, First, I have Installed Magento 2.1.7 with luma sample data, It's looking good, all products display very well and admin also working good. Come to the point, i need to change my theme. so i have downloaded free Magento 2  theme. My installation steps is, copy app and pub folder from downloaded package, move to my localhost root folder, finished. Then finally need to Running the Setup Wizard. Here is my error.

Comment: Did you get my point or i need to explain more?

Comment: No need to setup wizard again, you just added the theme. That's  it. and no need to pub folder, just copy the theme folder which is present inside the app->design->downloaded_theme_directory which you downloaded and paste it. run flush command.

Comment: may i know what is the error is this   https://snag.gy/x3hfby.jpg

Comment: it seems, custom theme folder are not placed properly or there might be any error in the theme file.

Comment: okay, let me check,, may i know what is the best way to import sample data theme after installed Magento 2 luma sample data theme.

Comment: Please try this, http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-install.html